# Assign a picture to a TImage and define the background color of transparent pixels

Tags: image, delphi, canvas, transparency, timage

**Problem:**
I have a TImage on a Delphi VCL form and want to assign a TGraphic.
The picture has transparent pixels.
When displaying the picture inside the TImage I want to display all transparent pixels in the color clBlue.
Unfortunately TImage does not have a property for a background color.

**What I have already tried:**

Fill the TImage with blue and afterwards to assign the picture:

```
MyImage.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
MyImage.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;
MyImage.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, MyImage.Width, MyImage.Height));
MyImage.Picture.Assign(MyGraphic);
```

Set the TransparentColor of the bitmap:

```
MyImage.Picture.Bitmap.TransparentColor := clBlue;
MyImage.Picture.Assign(MyGraphic);
```

Nothing worked :-(

Comment: You give the impression that your `MyImageList` is of type `TImageList`. But in my Delphi version 10.4 `MyImageList[1]` gives an error: `[dcc32 Error] Unit5.pas(39): E2149 Class does not have a default property`.

Comment: You are right. It is not a "TImageList" but a TGraphic where the picture is stored in. In my program it's implemented like `property MyImageList[Index: Integer]: TGraphic read GetMyImageList;`

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `TBitmap` of the desired size, and fill it completely with a solid `clBlue` color.

Then, draw the source image transparently onto this `TBitmap`, so that the blue color shows through the transparent areas.

Then, assign this `TBitmap` to the `TImage`.

---

Alternatively, place the `TImage` onto a `TPanel`, set the panel's color to `clBlue`, and then assign the transparent image as-is to the `TImage`.

---

Alternatively, use a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`. In the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event, draw a `clBlue` background onto the `TPaintBox.Canvas`, then draw the source image transparently onto the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure DrawPictureWithBackgroundColor(Image: TImage; Graphic: TGraphic; BackgroundColor: TColor);
begin
  Image.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  Image.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackgroundColor;
  Image.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height));
  Image.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height), Graphic);
end;
```

Usage:

```
DrawPictureWithBackgroundColor(MyImage, MyGraphic, clBlue);
```

MyGraphic contains the picture data itself.
MyImage is the control/container which makes the picture visible on the form.

Comment: This implies the requirement that source and destination must have the same dimensions.